# How can I add Excel secondary axis label via PowerShell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I can successfully add a Y axis label on the primary y axis of an excel graph using these lines:

```
# Work with the y axis
$yaxis = $firstchart.Axes($excelAxes::XlValue)
$yaxis.HasTitle  = $true
$yaxis.AxisTitle.Text = "Duration (sec)"
$yaxis.AxisTitle.Font.Size = 12
```

And I can successfully add a secondary y axis with the correct scale.  I have tried everything I can think of to add a label to the second axis, but nothing works.  For example:

```
$yaxis = $firstchart.Axes($excelAxes::XlValue::XlSecondary)
```

But this does not work (it results in errors).

[image: Link to Excel graph]

Comment: What's the errors you receive?  Also, can you show where you're defining `$excelAxes`?  I'm pretty confident what you might be doing, but it's better that we see explicitly (see: How to create a [mcve]).

Comment: Yes, I should have included that: $excelAxes = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisType]

Comment: The error I get is Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the second axis set using a second argument on the Axes method of the chart object.  $xlChart.Axes(A,B) where in A represents the axis (1 = X, 2 = Y), B represents the axis group (1,2).

The code below should get you what you want.

```
$xlChart.Axes(2,2).HasTitle = $true
$xlChart.Axes(2,2).AxisTitle.Text = "Label"
```

Comment: I get "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component." when trying this. The other calls to the chart and worksheet are working fine.